# Explain logic behind this TDD test with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I'm following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

To validate the presence and length of the users name and email, first of all write, you write:

```
validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :email, presence: true
```

which I can understand and find logical, but what I don't understand is the test in the spec/models/user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

    describe "when password is not present" do
        before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
      before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
      before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end
end
```

Is that not just forcing a condition that will clearly not be valid, satisfying the `should_not be_valid` test, what exactly is this test meant to do?

Comment: Make sure the validations meet your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test is meant to ensure that if the attribute values are outside of the acceptable bounds, the validation mechanism being tested will "catch it" and indicate that the record is not valid.

Comment: So am I right in saying if the first validation fails (validates :email, presence: true) rails will then refer to the test, which will fail? I though the user_spec.rb was just for the development/test environment, so how would that work in production?

Comment: If the first test fails, RSpec will report the discrepancy, not Rails.  RSpec would just be detecting that the value of `valid?` reported by Rails is not matching the example expectations.

Comment: So when you say 'outside of the acceptable bounds', is that the bounds set by the first test in the user model?

Comment: Yes, although the `validates` code isn't typically referred to as a "test", that language being generally reserved for software which doesn't execute in production mode, which the `validates` code does. Note also that the `validates` call performed what that class is first defined provides the information that is used when the _actual_ validation takes place.

Comment: I'm not following your question. I assumed by "first validation step" you're referring to the first `validates` call in your model. Both of those calls are part of your production code.  They tell Rails what constitutes an acceptable instance of the model.  All the other stuff is part of your spec.  Nothing in the model replaces anything in your spec.

Comment: Ok, I understand the first `validates` check, but what I don't understand is why the `@user` variable is created and sample content is provided in the RSpec file and I don't really understand the point of the RSpec tests?

Comment: It would help if you showed the rest of your spec, but the `@user` variable presumably refers to an instance of `User`. The sample content is the "input" part of the examples. Just as you'd test a `sum` function by providing (say) input of `2` and `3` expecting `5`, so here are you providing various values of `User` attributes and checking the behavior of the model's `valid?` function.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the full file. Also, this file is in the model folder, not requests if that makes any difference?

Comment: Ok, you're creating a new instance of the `User` model, referencing it as your `subject` and then running tests against it (i.e. setting attributes, invoking the `valid?` method on through your RSpec matchers and then checking the results to see if they are what you expected). I'm still not understanding how this seems unusual. Did my comparison to testing `sum` make any sense?

Comment: I just can't really get a grasp of the logic behind it? In reference to `sum`, is it not the same as declaring a function and then within that function declaring two variables, one is equalt to 2 and another = 3, then adding them together and expecting 5. It's obviously going to pass so what's the point?

Also, are the RSpec tests designed to check if the validation checks are working, not check if the user input is valid?

Comment: Ok, maybe we're getting closer here. In this example, `@user` is declared _in the test_, not within the function, and the setting of the attributes happens in the test as well. The only code that's in the _function_ are the calls to `validates`, which you're not touching.  And yes, the RSpec tests are testing to make sure that the validation checks in the model are working, by synthesizing a `User` instance, setting attrs on it and then invoking the model's validity tests.  That's sort of like generating a `2` (Integer)  sending a `sum` method to it along with a `3` that you've also created.

Comment: So in essence is it just doing the same validation test but with different means? If that's the case what would I have to do to make it fail, where do it come in useful?

Comment: I wouldn't say it or think of it that way. It's testing the production validation code. The tests you have now will fail if the validation ever stops working correctly (i.e. if the production validation code starts generating false negatives or false positives). You could make the test fail by changing the production code so it doesn't do the validation as it should (or by changing the test so that example data that doesn't fit the expected outcome).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now, the RSpec tests do certain actions using the `before` method as an example and interact with the app without you having to do anything, then it says that the app should respond in a certain way (the way it responds is defined by the `validates` method in the user model), if it doesn't the test has failed? Is that correct?

Comment: Yep. Specifically, RSpec will report a failure. If I were you, I would go ahead and play around with causing the test to fail by changing the production code and (if you want, after restoring the production code) changing the test code.

Comment: I'll definitely be working on it more now, Rails Tutorial incorporates a lot of TDD which is very helpful. I think the main reason I couldn't grasp it was that I though the RSpec tests would be client side and involved in the production environment and that I didn't realise the RSpec causes the user.rb to run but not visa versa. Anyway, thanks for the help! Much appreciated.